# How to write a console application that uses powershell instead of cmd

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, console

I have no idea if this is even a programming question, or something that is configured through my OS.  But how would I get it so my console application uses Powershell instead of cmd?  I know I can open Powershell and run the program from there, but even then, calls such as `system("Get-Childitem")` fail.

I'm using Visual C++ by the way, if that matters.  But if it's a compiler specific thing, then I would also like to know how to do it with GCC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into the environment variable COMSPEC, which on Windows, and DOS 1.1 before that, controls which shell is utilized for launching programs that need a shell.

```
SET COMSPEC=%path_to_powershell%
```

You can do the same within your C++ program by calling the [`setenv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setenv.html) C runtime call;